# PopupView not showing up?

Tags: android, popupwindow

Here's the XML (just a webview):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/couponView" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="100dp" />
```

and the code:

```
final View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.couponlayout, null);
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(cView);
pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), Gravity.CENTER, 100, 100);
pw.update();
```

This is in a button.onClick() method. When I click the button, the rest of the things that should happen (button changes color, text, etc.), but the PopupWindow doesn't show up. I've been combing the web but can't find any fixes. What am I doing wrong?

edit: no one knows whats going on? I feel like this is a common problem.

Answer (score 27):

```
PopupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

NOTE: setWindowLayoutMode has been deprecated. Use setHeight and setWidth.

Comment: +1 I was trying to find a way to use Scott's answer without having to use static height/width values. This helped a lot!

Comment: On second thought, the getWidth() and getHeight() methods for popupwindows returns 0 if you use this approach. You can instead get the width and height from the view inside the popup and set those as the popup's dimensions to simulate a wrap_content. Like this: popupWindow.setContentView(myView); popupWindow.setHeight(myView.getHeight()); popupWindow.setWidth(myView.getWidth());

Comment: setWindowLayoutMode has been deprecated. They want you to use setHeight and setWidth from now on.

Comment: This method is now deprecated in API 23. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setWindowLayoutMode(int, int)

Answer (score 11):

The PopupWindow probably has a width and height of 0 since the dimensions weren't initialized, which would explain why you can't see anything.  You can set the height and width with `setHeight` and `setWidth`, or do it with the constructor `PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height)`.

Check the Android [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for more info.