# Android - PopupWindow not showing when using post

Tags: android, popupwindow

When I call showAsDropDown without post, (i.e., straight in code) I see the popup -

```
PopupWindow w = new PopupWindow(v.getContext());
w.showAsDropDown(v);
```

however, when I'm trying to use `v.post()` (either with or without delay), I do not see the popup.

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                w.showAsDropDown(v);
            }
        });
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I feel rather foolish, but I've found the problem, and am leaving the question + solution for future generations -

The problem was that I forgot to call update in the post :)

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                w.showAsDropDown(v);
                w.update(v, 0, 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
        });
```

this code works.

Comment: Not sure if update is necessary. I suspect you just needed to set the dimensions of your popupwindow, and the update did that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504755/popupview-not-showing-up.

Comment: A PopupWindow's layout params are set to 0 by default. This means it expects an explicit size. You should either give it a size or change it's layout params to wrap_content or match_parent: `pw.setWindowLayoutMode(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`. That's why update works.